# How can I extract data for jqCharts from an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How can I extract data for jqCharts from an array of objects?

```
[{
    Catagories: 78, 
    Value1: 78
},{
    Catagories: 5,         
    Value1: 5
},{           
    Catagories: 5, 
    Value1: 5
},{
    Catagories: 79, 
    Value1: 79
}]
```

I want to do this in javascript. When I created this data by concatenating strings it does not work. I also tried this but it did not work

```
JSON.parse(string)
```

My code is:

```
$.each(datatogen, function (key, value) {
    var datatomo = "";
    $.each(value, function (key1, value1) {
        datatomo = "{Catagories: " + value1 + ", Value1: " + value1 + "}";
    });
    makedatato += datatomo;
});
```

How can I prepare this type of data? If it is in string I can convert it into a JSON object? Please help me.

Comment: What you have is an array of objects, so there's no need to parse them to JSON. You just need to loop over the array and retrieve the required values. You haven't specified what format you need, nor shown any attempt to solve this yourself, so your question is almost un-answerable at the moment.

Comment: please check it i have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way that you can prepare your object array. No need to output as a string, then parse it.
Please try this:

```
var output = [];
$.each(datatogen, function (key, value) {
var datatomo = {};
$.each(value, function (key1, value1) {
  datatomo.Catagories = value1;
  datatomo.Value1 = value1 ;
});
output.push(datatomo);
});
```